# Svg height greater than path height

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to make the top edge of a website footer wavvy by using a svg.

My svg:

```html
<svg id="footer_svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1335 190.97">
    <path class="cls-2" d="M924.04,146.21c-76.43,5.57-72.82,6.94-181.21,15.68-101.37,8.17-186.53,15.03-294.66,19.39-127.28,5.13-225.98,4.36-297.61,3.71-44.28-.4-94.82-1.28-150.55-3v10.98H1335v-63.26c-40.08,.65-76.99,1.52-110.4,2.47-84.89,2.41-179.64,5.22-300.56,14.03Z"></path>
</svg>
```

For some reason, the svg ends up with height=272.22px but the path height=90.17px.
I can't see any css settings that interferes with anything here.

Here's the result I'm getting:
[image: result]

I want to get rid of this extra white space:
[image: this extra white space].

Can anyone advise please?

NB: I'm not very experienced and have rarely used svgs before so it's very possible I've left something out or I've overlooked something. I've already tried looking this up but couldn't come up with a solution. All I can find is in relation to making the path the same height as the svg element but I want to achieve the opposite.

Many thanks!

Comment: Try this viewBox instead: `viewBox="0 129.7 1335 64"`

Comment: did you try any other `svg`??

Comment: @enxaneta This worked like a charm! I knew it'd be something this obvious, many thanks! :) Maybe post this as an answer and I'll mark it as the solution? Also, would you care to explain why it works? Thanks again! :)

Comment: I'm using getBBox() on the path. This is returning an object with the position of the upper left corner of the bounding box the width and the height. When you calculate the new value of the viewBox you will use the bounding box (bb) like `viewBox = bb.x bb.y bb.width bb.height`. In the case when you have a very thick stroke you may need to tweak those values

Answer (score 1):

The width and en height of the viewbox should match the size of the elements in the SVG. Your path has a height of 63.26, so here I moved up the path shape and made the height of the viewbox 63.26.

```html
<svg id="footer_svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1335 63.26">
    <path class="cls-2" d="M 924.04 16.5 c -76.43 5.57 -72.82 6.94 -181.21 15.68 c -101.37 8.17 -186.53 15.03 -294.66 19.39 c -127.28 5.13 -225.98 4.36 -297.61 3.71 c -44.28 -0.4 -94.82 -1.28 -150.55 -3 v 10.98 H 1335 v -63.26 c -40.08 0.65 -76.99 1.52 -110.4 2.47 c -84.89 2.41 -179.64 5.22 -300.56 14.03 Z"></path>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `preserveAspectRatio="none"`:

```css
svg {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox='0 0 100 100' preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <path d="M 0,80 C 50,120 50,-50 100,20 V 100 H 0 Z" fill='lightblue' />
</svg>
```